# SnapSVG trigger path click

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I am unable to fire off a click event on the path AND OR the group.  Im only assuming that its the group I should be concerned with. Ive tried triggering the group with the same result.

Here is the basic structure of the svg area.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="region1">
<path id="path1" d="..."></path>
<path id="path2" d="..."></path>
<path id="path3" d="..."></path>
<path id="path4" d="..."></path>
<g>
<g id="region2">
<path id="path5" d="..."></path>
<path id="path6" d="..."></path>
<path id="path7" d="..."></path>
<path id="path8" d="..."></path>
<g>
</svg>
```

This Dropdown should trigger a click event on the region

```
<select name="region-select" class="form-control" id="region-selection">
<option value="null">Select a region</option>
<option value="region1">Region 1</option>
<option value="region2">Region 2</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="submit" title="Go">Go</a></div>
```

The click event so far is logging the correct paths within each group/region.

```
$("#submit").bind("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var optionVal = $('#region-selection').val(),
      paths = Snap.select('g#'+regionSelected).children("path");

  console.log(paths);//returns the correct paths!EDIT::Returns the correct paths '.node.childNodes'...coppied from chrome.
  //console.log(paths.node); //Returns the DOM NODE

  // Now click the path 
  paths.trigger("click");//returns Uncaught TypeError: selected.trigger is not a function
});
```

This click event doesn't need to do very much except call a separate function handled else where in the JS. As long as the click is fired without error, Ill be satisfied.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE].

Comment: Snap doesn't have a trigger function. I think you may be mixing your JQuery and Snap methods up ?

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.  I will update my question